# Where can I find real ExpressJS (or any JS) application source code to read?

Tags: javascript, express, automated-tests

A great way to improve your own code is to read the code of others. I know there are many open source efforts out there but those tend to be APIs or modules that don't reflect common "real-world" implementation constraints or scenarios.

Where can I find real application code--preferably ExpressJS--that reflects best practices uses some form of test automation.

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: You cab go through [this}(https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=require+express&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Indeed... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out GitHub should provide you with enough reading for a lifetime!

[Look at the most starred projects using Express for example](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=using%20express&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: The "most starred" modification is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's best boilerplate about express in github.

https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter

"A boilerplate for Node.js web applications.

If you have attended any hackathons in the past, then you know how much time it takes to get a project started: decide on what to build, pick a programming language, pick a web framework, pick a CSS framework. A while later, you might have an initial project up on GitHub and only then can other team members start contributing. Or how about doing something as simple as Sign in with Facebook authentication? You can spend hours on it if you are not familiar with how OAuth 2.0 works.

When I started this project, my primary focus was on simplicity and ease of use. I also tried to make it as generic and reusable as possible to cover most use cases of hackathon web apps, without being too specific. In the worst case you can use this as a learning guide for your projects, if for example you are only interested in Sign in with Google authentication and nothing else.

Chances are you do not need all authentication methods or API examples. As of Hackathon Starter 2.1 it is possible to selectively check which authentication methods you need by running node setup.js."